# Show linear system have no, only one or many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Under what conditions on a and b will the following linear system have no solutions, one solution, infinitely many solutions?

first row: 2x − 3y = a second row: 4x − 6y = b

My work: I wrote the system as an augumented matrix and then multiply the first row by -2 and add it to the second row which makes the second row 0 0 -2a + b.

My Answer: It is infinitely many solutions when 2a = b because you can set a to be any arbitary value and it will solve b correctly. There is no solutions when it is the opposite: 2a is not equal to b.

Now I am stuck figuring out if it is even possible for it to have only one solution. This seems rather difficult since I shown it has many solutions. The only thing I can think of was to graph it and find the intersection of these two equations of a line. But can I replace a with x and b with y something like this: 2x = y?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Comment: You're making some confusion here. The unknowns are $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You will uncover everything very easily by writing this down as $A(x,y)^T=(a,b)^T$

Comment: The thing is this question pop up fairly early in the textbook: page 12 to be specific. Those two methods I can use are mentioned a lot later in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system will never have only one solution.

If $x=x_0, y=y_0$ is a solution to this system, then $x = x_0+3, y = y_0 + 2$ will also be a solution.

The other way to think of this is that two lines with the same slope can't intersect each other at only one point.

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence. As for the last sentence, doesn't two lines with the same slope are always parallel and not intersect?

Comment: @Nicholas not if they're the same line

Comment: An example to illustrate the second sentence: we know that $2(2) - 3(1) = 1$ and $4(2) - 6(1) = 2$, so that $x = 2, y=1$ is a solution for $a = 1$ and $b = 2$.  It follows that $x = 2 + 3 = 5$ and $y = 1 + 2 = 3$ will be another solution for the same system.

Comment: Overlapping lines counts an intersection?

Comment: @Nicholas yes; overlapping lines are said to intersect at every point.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 1):

It can have infinite solutions when it represents the same line so -

eg -
2x − 3y = 2

4x − 6y = 4

It can also represent a pair of parallel lines because they have the same slope -

eg -
2x − 3y = 1

4x − 6y = 3

Answer (score 0):

let us   write your system   again we have

$2*x-3*y=a$

$2*(2*x-3*y)=b$

from there we have

$2*a=b$

clearly for different value of $b$,we have different   $a$,now when  this system will not have solution,very easy if  we have following things

$2*x-3*y=6$

$4*x-6*y=7$

clearly it has not  solution,when

$2*x-3*y=6$

$4*x-6*y=12$

it have infinity solution,when it will have one solution? it could not have because  we always have    $2*a=b$

Comment: Great answer for the last sentence. That was the only thing I could not understand until I read it.

Comment: you are welcome  my friend